# Не установилась документация после установки Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

После установки Visual Studio 2010 при попытке установить документацию получил сообщение: "Расположение,указанное для хранилища содержимого справки, недопустимо или у Вас нет доступа к нему". В чем дело и что делать? Содержимое справки: файлы booki.html и файл HelpContentSetup.msha есть, но лежат в некоторой папке

Comment: честно говоря, в последний раз пользовался справкой, поставляемой с IDE года 3-4 тому назад, когда учился в институте. Затем все это было заменено на MSDN, SO и подобные ресурсы.

Впрочем, это не призыв "чувак, брось ты это, пользуйся интернетом", а всего лишь констатация факта

Comment: Попробуйте спросить на РутКод. А ещё, наверное, помог бы скриншот - на каком шаге инсталлятора это происходит. И не делайте дублей вопросов, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Скореетвсего у вас установлена ОС windows vista или более свежая, а также папка для расположения справки была выбрана на системном диске или диске с отсутствием прав на запись.
Запустила приложение для обновления справки от имени администратора (ПКМ - запуск от имени администратора) и попробуйте установить справку заново.